# Self join to show null Mangers in the query result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

table Employee

`emp_id   emp_name  emp_manager
1        Akshay       3
2        Santosh      3
3        Naveen       4
4        Prashanth    5
5        Punnet       Null`

fetch all   Mangers associated with employee

query

`SELECT a.emp_name, b.emp_name AS Manager
FROM employee AS a
INNER JOIN employee AS b ON a.emp_manager = b.emp_id`

`emp_name   Manager
Akshay     Naveen
Santosh    Naveen
Naveen     Prashanth
Prashanth  Punnet`

Null manager is not showing. 
How to write a query to show Punnet and manager as Null in the query result?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE emp_manager=NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT JOIN to get  NULL value.

Correction in your query:

```
SELECT a.emp_name, b.emp_name AS Manager
FROM employee AS a
LEFT JOIN employee AS b ON a.emp_manager = b.emp_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a LEFT JOIN instead:

```
SELECT a.emp_name, b.emp_name AS Manager
FROM employee AS a
LEFT JOIN employee AS b ON a.emp_manager = b.emp_id;
```

See [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) for more info joins.